# pyodbc sql query -substitution with shell variable

Tags: sql, shell, variables, substitution, pyodbc

Hi I have a shell script and I defined few variables in the shell. I want to use these variables in the python script. Here is an example
test.ksh

```
export var1=a123;
export var2=b345
```

py test.py

test.py

```
import sys
import os
import pyodbc
import pandas
import numpy
print os.environ['var1']
print os.environ['var2']
```

## read dataset to pandas data frame

```
sql = "'"
         sel a.*
from %var1.tablexyz_%var2 a 
"
```

iam expecting this to resolve to select * from a123.tablexyz_b345

how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sql = "select * from " + %var1 + ".tablexyz_"+ %var2
```